# Convert 'regexp_instr' (ORACLE) to equivalent in POSTGRESQL

Tags: regex, postgresql, database-migration, plpgsql

I came across an Oracle function when converting Oracle schema to Postgresql 12 as following:

```
varColName := upper(substr(inColumnDdl, regexp_instr(inColumnDdl, regMatch, 1, 1, 0, 'i', 1), regexp_instr(inColumnDdl, regMatch, 1, 1, 1, 'i', 1)-regexp_instr(inColumnDdl, regMatch, 1, 1, 0, 'i', 1)));
```

with the line : `regexp_instr(inColumnDdl, regMatch, 1, 1, 1, 'i', 1)-regexp_instr(inColumnDdl, regMatch, 1, 1, 0, 'i', 1)))`

regexp_instr gives the position of the last char in the occurence  - the position of the first char in the occurence

how can i do the same with probably strpos and regexp_match in postgresql, if you have any other idea instead strpos and regexp_match please tell me

an example : regexp_instr('stack', 'tac', 1, 1, 1, 'i', 1)-regexp_instr('stack', 'tac', 1, 1, 0, 'i', 1))). the first regexp_instr returns the value 4 which is the position of the last character of the occurence 'tac' in stack'.  AND the second regexp_instr returns the value 2 which is the position of the first character of the occurence 'tac' in stack' so the first regexp_instr - the second regexp_instr gives 4 - 2 = 2

Comment: Please provide some sample data (for `incolumnddl` and `regmatch`)  and the expected output based on that data.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name i added an example in the description ! thank you

Answer (score 0):

When migrating a database the first step to to make absolutely sure you know what the old database is doing. Unfortunately, in this case that seems to have failed. Your example description is incorrect. (See Oracle [SQL Language Reference](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/sqlrf/REGEXP_INSTR.html#GUID-D21B53A1-83E2-4722-9BBB-638470715DD6))

1. Both `regexp_instr` will return 0. This is due the the 7th (last)
   parameter. This parameter may be from 0-9 indicating the
   sub-expression within the *pattern* (in this case 'tag'). Your parameter
   value (1) indicates the first sub-expression. However there are no
   sub-expressions in your pattern. Therefore it returns 0. This is corrected by specifying 0 or omitting the parameter altogether.
2. The  first *regexp_instr returns the value 4* is incorrect it
   actually returns 5 (after correction for above). The 5th parameter
   *return_option* (1) does not return the last character of the
   pattern.

   > If you specify 1, then Oracle returns the position of the character
   > following the occurrence **of the matched pattern**.
   > (emphasis mine)
3. So the first regexp_instr - the second regexp_instr gives 5 - 2 = 3.
4. See [Oracle Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=f0b2c3f81b35f7660269404eefde4532)

Postgres, however, accomplishes the same much, much simpler. In a simple `substring(string from pattern)` statement. So ([Postgres demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=8c167ef68daf05f5c34112019819e496))

```
select upper(substring( incolumnddl from regmatch)) "Final Result"
  from table;
```

or as a Postgres function:

```
create or replace function example( incolumnddl text  
                                  , regmatch    text
                                  )
  returns text 
 language sql 
as $$
    select upper(substring( incolumnddl from regmatch)); 
$$;
```

select * from example ( 'stack', 'tac' ) "Final Result";